# How to send a pandas dataframe to a H2O cluster deployed on Google cloud platform through marketplace?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, h2o

I have a H2O cluster running on Google Cloud Platform Compute Engine which has been deployed through Marketplace and I want to send some data for analysis.

Data are ideally in the form of a Pandas dataframe, loaded in memory on my local machine. Alternatively I have the same data stored in a BigQuery table or in a csv file.

I tried the following code (illustrative example):

```py
import h2o
import pandas as pd

def connect_and_send_data(my_dataframe)
  username = "xxx"
  password = "yyy"

  h2o.connect(url="http://xx.xx.xx.xx:443", auth(username,password), verify_ssl_certificates=False)

  h2o.H2OFrame(my_dataframe, destination_frame = "train_df")
```

For dataframes bigger than, let's say, 200 rows, I get the following error message:

```html
H2OServerError: HTTP 413 Request Entity Too Large:
'<html>\r\n<head><title>413 Request Entity Too Large</title></head>\r\n<body bgcolor="white">\r\n<center><h1>413 Request Entity Too Large</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n'
```

Note that the code above works perfectly if I pass a small pandas dataframe, or on a H2O cluster created on my local machine, regardless the size of data, to which I connect by using

```py
h2o.init()
```

instead of

```py
h2o.connect()
```

I tried also to upload a csv file from the flow or using the function

```py
h2o.upload_file(path="somecsvfile.csv")
```

but still, no success.

Any idea on how I can quickly sort out this issue?